# Need some foods or fruits recommendation for before and after gym workout

Tags: workout-routines, training, post-workout, pre-workout

Can anybody recommends me the food or fruits or anythings which would help me in my workout before work out and after work out??

I am doing body building at the gym.

Usually before half an hour i eat 1 packet of biscuits with milk and after half an hour i go to the gym.

I go to the gym at 8 30 pm and comes from gym around 9 45 pm and then after 1 hour i eat my dinner.

So is this a good routine or bad??

Can anybody recommends me whether i am doing wrong or right??

Comment: It depends... What are your goals? What is your overall daily nutrition plan? What train routine are you following? What is your TDEE?

Comment: A pack of biscuits probably isn't a top tier nutrition choice.

Comment: @joao:My goal is to build a medium body not a bulky body.My overall nutrition plan is in the morning i eat some grams with 2 chapatis containing jam with milk and in the lunch i eat 4 chapatis and in the night i am planning to skip dinner and just eat 2 bananas only.I dont eat rice in my lunch.So can you tell me the mistake in my daily plan if you think that something is wrong

Comment: @EricKaufman:My goal is to build a medium body not a bulky body.My overall nutrition plan is in the morning i eat some grams with 2 chapatis containing jam with milk and in the lunch i eat 4 chapatis and in the night i am planning to skip dinner and just eat 2 bananas only.I dont eat rice in my lunch.So can you tell me the mistake in my daily plan if you think that something is wrong

Comment: It seems your nutrition consists of a lot of carbs and not enough proteins. Also, why only chapatis? I don't see any veggies, chicken, eggs, turkey, or any of the vegan protein items. You need more protein!

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD:But how can you say my nutrition consist alot of carbs? and i just eat chapatis and not rice because i dont want to increase my weight so.can you please guide me what are the mistakes i am doing?

Comment: According to Wikipedia and Google, **Chapatis** is a form of bread. It's carb and it's certainly in the same category as rice. Carbs won't make you big; they'll make you gain fat though, unless you burn them a lot. But more importantly, you need protein for growth. You need veggies for the essential minerals and vitamins that your body needs. Your current food intake doesn't seem to be providing you these essential nutrients.

Comment: @Learning I see that you are worried about gaining bulk. But this is a common misunderstanding... It is incredibly hard to "bulk" up, you have to be VERY intentional about it. Eating 400-500 calories more than your daily requirement, and taking in mass amounts of protein. Don't avoid protein because you're worried about bulk. Lift, eat a regular healthy diet, and you'll gain what you're after! :) Eat too many carbs, you run the risk of not burning them fast enough. This will gain you fat, which I doubt you are after...

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD:Can you recommend me some best affordable source of protein but not body building supplements because body building supplements harm our body in long run and most importantly when we stop doing exercise then our body shape becomes wierd(means the way it was before we have started exercise or join gym).apart from that any source of protein tablets or something that which can only provied necessary proteins in my body and no side effects to my body??

Comment: @jsmith:Can you recommend me some best affordable source of protein but not body building supplements because body building supplements harm our body in long run and most importantly when we stop doing exercise then our body shape becomes wierd(means the way it was before we have started exercise or join gym).apart from that any source of protein tablets or something that which can only provied necessary proteins in my body and no side effects to my body??

Comment: Rather than giving you specific protein meals, I'd rather you use Google and visit your local grocery stores. There are protein items for meat lovers, vegans, and vegetarians alike. You have a lot of local resources; use them.

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD:thank you so much for all your kind advices.Thank you so much.but am i doing right thing like eating only chapatis in lunch and not eating rice just thinking i would gain weight by eating rice??

Comment: As others have said, ***the only weight you'll gain by eating chapatis/rice/carb-based diet is fat.*** To build muscles, you need to consume more protein meals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the workout it is not very recommended for it to be something heavy. It should be a light snack 30-60 minutes before the workout. I got here two videos with good examples of things you can eat:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7vVY0wZdrHU

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2h0i1ZEOeyc

So mostly complex-carbs to give the needed energy to the body, try to avoid simple carbs as they will give you a short boost followed by a fall in energy mid-workout.
I usually try to schedule my workout with my supper so you won't have to eat another meal in order to give the body its needs. It should be about 30-60 minutes after workout and should contain proteins to help the muscles recover and complex carbs as well to give it some energy again.
Try also to drink a lot of water in overall and try not to eat big meals before the workout cause it will make your body focus on digesting and training at the same time which will be much harder.

Comment: My goal is to build a medium body not a bulky body.My overall nutrition plan is in the morning i eat some grams with 2 chapatis containing jam with milk and in the lunch i eat 4 chapatis and in the night i am planning to skip dinner and just eat 2 bananas only.I dont eat rice in my lunch.So can you tell me the mistake in my daily plan if you think that something is wrong